# what is the purpose of the guided image filter's box filter?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter

Now I'm trying to understand the guided image filter with matlab.
when I run the matlab code of the guided image filter from here
http://kaiminghe.com/eccv10/

I came across some point what I can't understand.

1. guided image filter call the box filter.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44oSn.jpg)
   But I can't understand this. what is the purpose of the guided image filter's box filter? it seems like this. [How does the box filter look like (SURF) (DoB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36161572/how-does-the-box-filter-look-like-surf-dob) but boundary not the same.
2. when I just modified the box filter's coefficients to all the same like as 81, I use the one number as 81 instead of except for boundary pixels. then I found that guided image filter doesn't not work as well. so I thought that the output of box filter's coefficients are supposed to have boundary pixels.
   why does box filter's boundary pixels have to be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Box Filter is also known as a Mean Filter. The parameter you're passing the box filter is the kernel size. The size of the kernel dictates how many pixels in some NxN neighborhood to average together. This is a well-known form of Low-Pass Filtering used for smoothing out the noise in an image. If you pass the box filter a kernel size of 81, you'll be averaging a square of 81x81; I would stick to something like a 3x3 or 5x5 filter to maintain a better level of detail in your image.